# extval bean validation xml mapping

Tags: java, validation, jsf, bean-validation, hibernate-validator

I trying to use extval based on xml validation but it doesn't work . it's work fine based on annotation . xml validation working fine if i use any native JSR 303  validation or hibernate validation.Is the extval support valdaition based xml or no ? .
this is my configuration 
validation.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<validation-config
    xmlns="http://jboss.org/xml/ns/javax/validation/configuration"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://jboss.org/xml/ns/javax/validation/configuration">
    <constraint-mapping>META-INF/constraints-login.xml</constraint-mapping>
</validation-config>
```

constraints-login.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<constraint-mappings xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://jboss.org/xml/ns/javax/validation/mapping validation-mapping-1.0.xsd"
    xmlns="http://jboss.org/xml/ns/javax/validation/mapping">
    <default-package>com.beans</default-package>
    <bean class="LoginBean" ignore-annotations="false">
        <field name="userName">
            <constraint annotation="org.apache.myfaces.extensions.validator.baseval.annotation.Required"/>
        </field>
    </bean>
</constraint-mappings>
```

---

Comment: I have a really hard time understanding what you are asking here, but _rg.apache.myfaces.extensions.validator.baseval.annotation.Required_ is no Bean Validation annotation, so I am not surprised that you are having problems. In fact I would expect exceptions to be thrown. Something you don't even mention.

Comment: thanks for your answer , as i understand extval is a custom validation constraint and i can configure my custom validation constraint as xml and annotation. but when i configure extval custom validation as a xml it dosn't work and the error is javax.servlet.ServletException: HV000012: Unable to create annotation for configured constraint